# Why max and min functions are returning unexpected results using Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I am using ECG data in csv format and read the data as:

```
myECG = pd.read_csv('ECG_MIT.csv');
```

Then I extracted a column called 'ECG" from the above read data (I am calling it as ECG_data) and attempted to derive some useful metrics. These include the following.

```
print 'Max val in ECG: ', ECG_data.max();  #reports 1023

print 'Min val in ECG: ', ECG_data.min(); # reports 0
```

The results are wrong as I see the max value itself is 800 and min value is 474 via Excel's max and min functions. Also I printed sample values and checked. I also used alternate forms like "max(ECG_data)" and "min()".

Also, when I use:

```
print  "Data Summary: \n",myECG.describe()
```

I seem to see the same wrong values in the statistics reported. What am I doing wrong here? Pls help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you attach part of your dataframe? Because it's hard to tell what's going wrong without data.

Comment: it would help if you showed how you extracted the `ECG_data` column

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions for you birdie:
1. Based on your examples, i'm going to assume your data is all integers.
2. Next step will be to validate that. If it's not integers, then convert it.
3. Sort your data in excel ascending to confirm what your excel min and max functions are yielding.
4. How does that differ from pandas?
5. In pandas, try calling the min or max function with the column name.

How this helps!

Comment: That is exactly the case. I have only integers. As I mentioned I used excel to extract the max and min values. I also use pandas max and min functions too - myECG is the read values from csv file. It has ECG as a column which has all integers. So I extracted these ECG values to a df called ECG_data. Then I used all sorts of max and min functions - ECG_data.max()  and also tried max(ECG_data), etc. All are printing 1023 as the value and the ECG column in the csv file has a max value as just 800 as generated by excel.

Comment: Following is the ECG column in my csv file. I had extracted and pandas printed it correctly as follows. (sample values are here) 
575
573
572
573
575
576
578
578
579
579

Answer (score 0):

`0` and `1023` happen to be the min and max values of a 10 bit integer.

So you are probably getting the min/max values of some *limits* of your object (buffers, for example, tend to grow in powers of 2, and 1024 is one of them).

You will need to check if `ECG_data` is the right type of object, and if you're using the `min()`/`max()` functions in the correct way.

Comment: You may be right. But even before deriving max and min values I used myECG.describe() function that usually tells all about the data (mean, median, max, min and count, etc). In this summary of results I also observe that the max and min values to be 1023.00 and 0, respectively!! This display is right after reading the csv file using pd.read_csv() command as I had mentioned in my original post.  In my other programs there seems to be no issues!!  Strange.... I am digging out still...